# Issue when rendering a ListViewItem in Xamarin ListView

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Using a ListView in Xamarin, Most of the time, it works well, but for some items, I get a rendering issue, items in the StackLayout are overlapping (stacking on Z axis instead of Y axis!), I am wondering what could cause that:

[image: Issue]

It seems to happen when cells are recycled to a different height that they initially had.

The xaml is quite simple, a binding for the ListView (grouped) and itemtemplate:

```xml
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Padding="10,5" BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}">
                <!-- The following IsVisible property is probably what cause 
                     the change of height of cells, and when recycled, 
                     the cells do not resize well -->
                <Label Text="{Binding Date}" TextColor="Black" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                       IsVisible="{Binding Date,Converter={StaticResource INNTBC}}" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" FontSize="12" />
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Participant.FirstName}" TextColor="Black" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" FontSize="16" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Participant.LastName}" TextColor="Black" ineBreakMode="NoWrap" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" FontSize="16" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Participant.BirthDate}" TextColor="Black" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" FontSize="12" />
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="LightGray" Margin="20,1,20,1" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Any clue?

Comment: have you tried by adding spacing for the main stack layput in the viewCell

Comment: Try `HasUnevenRows="True"` on your ListView.

Comment: @Vahid thanks, but it is already there, as well as `CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"`

Comment: @Argon unfortunately, `Spacing="1"` did not solve the issue :(
Actually the issue comes from the `CachingStrategy`, which is causing the bug.

Comment: @Jean did you solved it?

Comment: @AndroDevil Yes and no. See the answer below. I am still looking for a better solution, but my temporary solution works for now. And I am pretty sure I have already faced that kind of issue.

Comment: Why dont you use a grid?

Comment: Good question... It was at first for simplicity. I will give it a try later today.

Comment: @Jean Did you solved it? Do you need help?

Comment: For now I am working on other UI parts, as this one is temporary solved. I have used a Grid as suggested, but it is still on fixed height, so I will have to investigate further later with `HasUnevenRows=True"`

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from `CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"` applied to the `ListView`. The height is not well recalculated when recycled.

This is not optimal but at the end I solved it by setting a `RowHeight` to the ListView.